NCSPOT | Bad credentials
I have a premium membership and wanted to use ncspot. I tried login using my regular username and password that works successfully on the website. But when i try to login using the same credentials via ncspot, I get this Bad Credentials error.
I have tried logging in with regular user name and password that works fine on the website and app.

Same here or arch linux package version 1.1.0-1

Found a fix on this github issue:
https://github.com/hrkfdn/ncspot/issues/1500
Breakdown is, create a credentials.json with the gnome spotify client + https://github.com/dspearson/librespot-auth and place in:
~/.var/app/io.github.hrkfdn.ncspot/cache/ncspot/librespot/
YMMV
GL!
